# Compile and test Windows Forms Controls without launching full application?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm developing a control for a large Windows Forms application. The control is currently housed in a class library along with the the control onto which it will go. Is there an easy way to compile and execute *only the control* (and any relevant dependencies, of course) in some sort of test form without having to launch the entire application?

I'm using Visual C# 2010 express.

Comment: In these situations I just make a "scrap" project (an empty windows form project) and develop what I need there. When the time comes to integrate it into the main application I just copy the files I need over and leave behind the testing data. I guess that is my way of saying, no, you can't just compile a couple files and run them. You can go into your Program class and change the form you start on or stop it from running a form and just execute some methods with break points, but that is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another Win.Form project just for testing that control. Ideally, the control would be in its own project as well, so you avoid having to rebuild the whole application just to test the control.

Comment: Is it easy to pull the control out of the test project and drop it into the other? Any caveats?

Comment: Well if you have code for the control in the test project, and another one in the main project, that means you have *two* sets of identical code that you need to maintain. So you'd be better off putting the control in it's own project and use it in both the main project and the test project.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build the control within its own Project.  If you do this, you could execute the control within a form developed specifically for that project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at running all the stuff you don't want to run in non Debug mode and the stuff you want to test in debug mode

```
    #if DEBUG
// do debug only stuff 
#else
// Release stuff
#endif
```

Comment: First of all, does C# support such "preprocessor directives"? Secondly, the code base I'm working with is far too large and interwoven for this to be particularly practical. It would be easier to build from scratch, I think.